# How to iterate an object over a list of objects in JSTL?

Tags: java, jstl

I have a class named `Language` with 1 field named `name`. I have another class named `Speech` which has a `language` member. I need to iterate over a list of `Speech` objects. In JSTL:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.Speech}" var="speech">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;${speech.id}</td>
    <td>&nbsp;${speech.language.name}</td>
  </tr> 
</c:forEach>
```

My second statement `${speech.language.name}` doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Speech and Language classes:

```
public class Speech {
    private int id;
    private Language language=null;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
    public void setLanguage(Language language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
}

public class Language {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does it mean, "doesn't work"? Could you please attach an exception trace? Could you also post here your classes "speech" and "language"?

Comment: Can you post the code of your `Speech` and `Language` class?

Comment: Please, provide code for Language class. Is there valid getter for name field? Is there valid getter for instance of Language class in Speech class?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your `Speech` class has a `public Language getLanguage()` method defined.

Answer (score 2):

The JSP EL doesn't use fields. It uses properties. In order for this statement to work, you need to have a public method `getLanguage()` in `Speech`, and a public method `getName()` in `Language`.

EDIT:

If the getters are there, and nothing is being printed, it can have four reasons:

- there is no `Speech` attribute in the request
- there is a list of Speeches in the Speech request attribute, but this list is empty
- the language of each Speech of the list is null
- the name of each Language is null or blank.

If something is printed for the speech ID, it eliminates the first two reasons.