# iterating over list of objects jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I know this question has been asked previously - [How to iterate an object over a list of objects in JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711251/how-to-iterate-a-object-over-a-list-of-objects-in-jstl). I tried the suggestions but still no luck.

POJO

```
public class VwSfuser implements java.io.Serializable {
private VwSfuserId id;
private String name;
private String userid;

public VwSfuser() {
}

public VwSfuser(VwSfuserId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public VwSfuserId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(VwSfuserId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}
  }
```

I am passing a List to jsp and trying to access like this:
JSTL

```
 <c:forEach items="${model.userNameList}" var="list">        
        <option value="${list.userid}">${list.name}</option>
      </c:forEach>
```

Now, what I get is:

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'userid' not found on type java.lang.String

Comment: Show your code of where you add the `userNameList` to the model.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `model.`

Try this:

```
<c:forEach items="${userNameList}" var="list">        
    <option value="${list.userid}">${list.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

If you have added the `userNameList` properly to the model, this should work.

Comment: FYI model is a Hashmap that I using like this:  model.put("userNameList", "VwSfuserNameList_all"); Hence, I ll have to  use model.userNameList

Comment: @user1736333 Sorry, I just assumed you were using Spring-MVC and it's methods. Seems like you have made something of your own here. Show more of your code from where you add it to the model. Especially the declaration of your `VwSfuserNameList_all` variable, if there is such a variable.

Comment: oh man.. .sorry for the trouble.. I did this  model.put("userNameList", "VwSfuserNameList_all"); instead of model.put("userNameList", VwSfuserNameList_all);..

Comment: @user1736333 I had a feeling that was the problem... I thought it was a bit strange. Glad you solved it.